# how to disable a draggable even if dropped into wrong droppable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I know how to disable draggable when the object is dragged into the correct droppable as you can see below but not when dropped into the wrong droppable.
I want the user to not be able to drag again even if the answer is incorrect, which means only one try.
I use edge animate which uses a different syntax to get the elements than plain JavaScript but the rest is the same.
Below is my code with comments.

```
for(j=0;j<35;j++){
    sym.$(answers1[j]).addClass('drag'+j);
    sym.$('.drag'+j).draggable({
    //revert: "invalid"   // I do not want revert in any case
    stop: function(){
        $(this).draggable('disabled');  // will disable when dropped anywhere
        //I want only when into the wrong droppable - 
        //so almost good but not quite right.
    }           
});

sym.$(droppables[j]).droppable({
    accept: ".drag"+j,
    drop: function(event,ui){
    ui.draggable.draggable( 'destroy' );  // the correct answer is disabled
    //I could have used 'disabled' here since it does the same as 'destroy'.
    } 
});
```

Comment: Either way works. the issue is to disable even when the answer is not correct. Right now of course it disable anywhere on the stage with the stop function. without the stop function, the draggable are disabled only when they are in the correct droppable which means the user can try any of the draggable until he gets the correct answer which I want to prevent.

Comment: Ok, got your update. What's the difference between the correct and incorrect ```droppable```? Can't you handle the ```drop``` event the same way for all of them disabling the draggable?

Comment: No. Maybe I can explain better. I have let's say 3 draggables and 3 droppables. Each draggable is accepted by it's corresponding droppable. If I drop .drag1 in droppable 1 it is correct and is disable and cannot be removed from the droppable. If I drag drag1 into droppable 2 then it continues to be draggable until it is put into droppable 1. what I want is the drag 1 stops being draggable even if it is dropped into droppable 2 or droppable 3 not just droppable 1.

Comment: Which means all of them should stop the draggable no matter if it matches the droppable or not. Or am I missing something again? =)

Comment: Right. Unfortunately if I use the stop function they get disabled anywhere on the stage. I want them to become disabled only when in any of the droppables whether correct or not.

Comment: Wonder if you need to be more specific in your `accept` option. It may need to be `accept: "div.drag" + j,`

Comment: @Twisty, what's wrong with dragging say ```<p>``` instead of a ```<div>``` ?

Comment: @dekkard absolutely nothing. I took a guess that OP was using `div` as a container versus `p`. Since they did not include enough HTML to determine this, I guessed `div`.

Comment: i will try this. I still need the correct  ones to be accepted and counted for my score variable though. Let me see if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the final and correct way it was done in Edge Animate.
The way to using data() in Edge Animate is a little different than plain javascript and html. We used it in order to be able to compare the  data value with the value of the variable ID. We also used one class for the draggables and added the class in the UI for the draggables that did not have a droppable (distractors) so they could still be dragged and placed in a droppable and act as all the other draggables. Then we added the conditional in the dropEvent function.

```
//'level1-D','level1-E','level1-F'  added the drag class in the UI for distractors.
var answers1 = [
'level1-A','level1-B','level1-C',
'level2-A','level2-B','level2-C',
'level3-A','level3-B','level3-C',
'level4-A','level4-B',
'level5-A','level5-B','level5-C',
'level6-A','level6-B','level6-C',
'level7-A','level7-B','level7-C','level7-D',
'level8-A','level8-B','level8-C','level8-D','level8-E',
'level9-A','level9-B','level9-C',
'level10-A','level10-B','level10-C',
];

var droppables = [
'dp0' ,'dp1' ,'dp2' ,'dp3' ,'dp4' ,'dp5' ,'dp8','dp6','dp7','dp9',
'dp10','dp13','dp11','dp12','dp15','dp16','dp14','dp19','dp17','dp20',
'dp18','dp23','dp22','dp21','dp25','dp24','dp27','dp26','dp28','dp29','dp30','dp31'
];

for(j=0;j<32;j++){
    // draggables
    sym.$(answers1[j]).addClass('drag');
    // droppables
    sym.$(droppables[j]).droppable({
    accept:'.drag',
    drop: dropEvent
    }).data('answer', answers1[j]);  // use data to be able to compare gives the same name as the draggables

}// end for loop
sym.$('.drag').draggable({
        revert : "invalid"      
});

k=0;
function dropEvent(event, ui){
    ui.draggable.draggable('option', 'revert' , false );
    ui.draggable.draggable('option','disabled', true ); 
    ui.draggable.position( { of: $(this), my: 'center', at: 'middle' } );
    ID = ui.draggable.attr("id").replace('Stage_','');
   if(ID == $(this).data('answer')){  // retrieve the data info and compare to ID 
       k++;
        sym.getSymbol("meter").play();
        sym.getSymbol("coinAnimation").play(0); 
        sym.$(ID + '-result').css({'opacity':1.0});
        sym.$("boxScore").html(k);
        sym.$("score").html(k+'/32');
        if (music.paused ) {
            correct.pause();    
        } else {
            correct.currentTime = 0;
            correct.play();
        }
    }// end if
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically your problem is that by using both `accept` and `drop` option you make the `drop` execute only for accepted elements.

In order to achieve what you want you'll have to use some other way to define that relation between a `draggable` and its "correct" `droppable`.

E.g. you could add a data attribute to each `droppable` that holds the class of the accepted `draggable` (say `data-accept="drag1"`).
Then you could remove the `accept` options from your `droppables` and in their `drop` handler manually check if the classes match, something like

```
drop: function( event, ui ) {
   if (ui.draggable.hasClass( $(this).data('accept') )) { 
        // correct match
   }

   // anyway disable the draggable
   ui.draggable.draggable('disable');
}
```

Here's a demo: **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dekkard/bxa0565j/)**

Comment: This does not explain why `accept` option of droppable would not work to do this. Please explain that further.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the issue. I thought OP wanted to only accept one specific draggable on to a specific droppable. In this way, droppable only accepts the correct answer that is dragged to it. All other answers are not accepted by that specific droppable.

Comment: Check out the author's 3rd comment.

Comment: OK, guys. check out my link. I do not have the non correct disabled in this one but I suppose this will give you a better idea of what I want. In question 1, if you drop anything it should stay where it is whether it is correct or not but at the same time if it is correct I have 2 visual feedback and also a counter.  http://mjpagedesign.com/sample/

Answer (score 0):

After getting some clarification, I offer this alternate solution. With multiple answers and places to drop them, when 1 answer is dropped, that should no longer accept answers, and users should not be able to move that answer further.

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/crdxcg90/3/

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <h4>Put the family members in order of youngest to oldest.</h4>
  <p class="drag answer" id="1">Homer</p>
  <p class="drag answer" id="2">Marge</p>
  <p class="drag answer" id="3">Bart</p>
  <p class="drag answer" id="4">Lisa</p>
  <p class="drag answer" id="5">Maggie</p>
</div>

<div class="dropzone drop1" id="drop-1">Youngest</div>
<div class="dropzone drop2" id="drop-2">2</div>
<div class="dropzone drop3" id="drop-3">3</div>
<div class="dropzone drop4" id="drop-4">4</div>
<div class="dropzone drop5" id="drop-5">Oldest</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.drag {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 3px;
  width: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2px;
}

.dropzone {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #0f0;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2px;
}

.answered {
  background: #cfc;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
$(function() {
  $(".answer").draggable({
    revert: "invalid"
  });
  $(".dropzone").droppable({
    drop: function(e, ui) {
      $(e.target).addClass("answered");
      ui.draggable.draggable("destroy");
      $(this).droppable("option", "accept", function() {
        return false;
      });
    }
  });
});
```

You would need to adjust back to your specific assignments, but this may make it easier on you and be more flexible if the number of answers changes often.

**Updated**

After looking at your sample, I can see more what you're going for. Hopefully this will help you:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/crdxcg90/6/

```
var answers1 = [1, 3, 5];
var coins = 0;
$(function() {
  $(".answer").draggable({
    revert: "invalid"
  });
  $(".dropzone").droppable({
    drop: function(e, ui) {
      $(e.target).addClass("answered");
      var t = parseInt($(e.target).attr("id").substring(5));
      var a = parseInt(ui.draggable.attr("id"));
      if (answers1[t] === a) {
        $(e.target).addClass("correct");
        coins++;
      }
      ui.draggable.draggable("destroy");
      $(this).droppable("option", "accept", false);
      $("#coins").html(coins);
    },
    tolerance: "fit"
  });
});
```

When the object is dropped, it checks that position in `answers1` if the drop matches the answer, we mark it correct and award a coin.

Comment: OK. I will see if I can adapt to my comp. I have lots of things going on. I have 10 questions with a different number of drag/drop. Each time something is dropped, some animation occurs if dropped is correct and something else if incorrect. At the same time I have a score for correct. So I still need to keep track of what is correct and have feedback too.

Comment: I tried to make one that uses a `for` loop, but if you make use of the classes, the selection becomes a lot easier. If you can make a working example in jsfiddle, update your question, and we might be able to help further.

Comment: BTW thanks for your answer. I feel like it is a step forward. I hope I can make it work with all the rest. - How do I check it as correct?

Comment: I do not know how to use fiddle since it is edge animate. I posted the example for you to see here: http://mjpagedesign.com/sample/

Comment: You example will not work because it does not allow all the rest to work. I need to twist my brain a little more to make this work.

Comment: Here is a new example, that can be used against an array of answers: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/crdxcg90/6/

Comment: I wonder if I could use data() to track the correct answers and use only one class like you did. Still working on it.

Comment: Sweet! Let me try to transfer the idea in Edge Animate. Thank you so much for your  examples.